# iOS controllers for custom views

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, separation-of-concerns

I'm all for trying to create lightweight view controllers (testability, separation of concern, etc. etc.), however, I've been unable to find a reasonable solution or pattern when it comes to certain cases.

A very common case (with plenty of examples out there) is separating the view controller from a tableview's delegate & datasource; I get this, it makes complete sense. But what about cases where a view controller may contain multiple custom views of varying complexity? What should be responsible for controlling each of those views? Surely not just the parent view controller.

I tend to think of a 'UIViewController' as more of a screen controller that is heavily coupled with the UI framework and its events; it does not have a single responsibility of controlling one particular view. To further illustrate my point, imagine a tableview with a couple of different prototype cells - some of which are fairly complicated and may require network access for instance - how should this be managed? Surely no single view controller, datasource or delegate should act as the "controller" for all of these cells? And a lot of that logic/responsibility does not belong in the cell views themselves, so it needs to be delegated somewhere.

One option I've thought of is to just create controller objects (subclasses of NSObject) that act as "view controllers" for the custom views I create, such as a controller object for a complex tableview cell - its single responsibility is to manage that one particular view. The tableview cell then delegates to the controller object, which then (if needed) delegates back to the parent UIViewController. Whilst this will work and helps to separate concerns, it starts to feel a bit awkward with all the layers of delegation going on.

Does anybody have any good suggestions on handling these scenarios or know of good code examples out there that demonstrates this?

Thanks!